# Filter top N values in column for each value in other column based on score pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

So I have a dataframe in Spark with the following data:

```
user_id item   category score
-------------------------------
user_1  item1  categoryA  8
user_1  item2  categoryA  7
user_1  item3  categoryA  6
user_1  item4  categoryD  5
user_1  item5  categoryD  4
user_2  item6  categoryB  7
user_2  item7  categoryB  7
user_2  item8  categoryB  7
user_2  item9  categoryA  4
user_2  item10 categoryE  2
user_2  item11 categoryE  1
```

And I want to filter it so I keep only 2 items of the same category for each user based on a score, so it should look like:

```
user_id item   category score
-------------------------------
user_1  item1  categoryA  8
user_1  item2  categoryA  7
user_1  item4  categoryD  5
user_1  item5  categoryD  4
user_2  item7  categoryB  7
user_2  item8  categoryB  7
user_2  item9  categoryA  4
user_2  item10 categoryE  2
user_2  item11 categoryE  1
```

Where item 3 and 6 were removed due to being a 3rd item of the same category for a user and had the lower score (or if equal score, dropped at random until there are only two items of that category).

I tried to do it with a partition over window like this:

```
df2 = test.withColumn(
    'rank', 
    F.rank().over(Window.partitionBy('user_id','category').orderBy(F.desc('score')))
).filter('rank <= 2')
```

That returned me:

```
user_id item   category score
-------------------------------
user_1  item1  categoryA  8
user_1  item2  categoryA  7
user_1  item4  categoryD  5
user_1  item5  categoryD  4
user_2  item6  categoryB  7
user_2  item7  categoryB  7
user_2  item8  categoryB  7
user_2  item9  categoryA  4
user_2  item10 categoryE  2
user_2  item11 categoryE  1
```

This works with user 1 but it wouldn't work with user 2 since it has items of the same category with equal score, so for items 6,7,8 that belong to categoryB and has score 7 will not filter any out. In this edge case I would like to filter one at random to have only 2.

Any idea on how to do this type of filtering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number` over a window partitioned by user_id and category:

```
df2 = df.withColumn(
    'rank',
    F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('user_id', 'category').orderBy(F.desc('score')))
).filter('rank <= 2').drop('rank').orderBy('user_id', 'item', 'category', F.desc('score'))

df2.show()
+-------+------+---------+-----+
|user_id|  item| category|score|
+-------+------+---------+-----+
| user_1| item1|categoryA|    8|
| user_1| item2|categoryA|    7|
| user_1| item4|categoryD|    5|
| user_1| item5|categoryD|    4|
| user_2|item10|categoryE|    2|
| user_2|item11|categoryE|    1|
| user_2| item7|categoryB|    7|
| user_2| item8|categoryB|    5|
| user_2| item9|categoryA|    4|
+-------+------+---------+-----+
```

Comment: Hi! I tried that too but it wouldnt work with items of the samecategory with the same score, I would like to filer them out too. I'll edit the main post with example. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @JaimeFerrandoHuertas you can use `row_number` instead. edited my answer.

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Thanks for the answer and sorry for not including that edge case in the first time.